# grunt undefined Method error?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gruntjs

I have an Angular App that uses grunt to build and minify. I have imported one library in index.html like this: `<script type="text/javascript"> java script code </script>` between the header tag. It is supposed to make the methods of that library globally available though my application. The problem is that when I run grunt to build my application, grunt doesn't recognize the method of that library. What should I do to fix it? 
The error I get in grunt is: 'the method I used' is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Use /* global **name of the method***/ at the top of the file where grunt gives you undefined error. it will make that method globally available. so you don't need to be worried about it.